# Running MALLET on Windows; could not find or load main class cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors

Tags: mallet

I'm trying to get [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/index.php) running on a 64-bit Windows 10 Enterprise machine from the native command prompt (`cmd.exe`). (I tried doing everything with Git Bash, but got stuck even earlier in the process.)

What I've done:

- Installed [JDK 8u281 for 64-bit Windows](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)
- Downloaded and installed MALLET 2.0.8 in my C:\
- Installed [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) in my C:\Program Files (per [this Medium post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/mallet-machine-learning-for-language-toolkit-installation-on-windows-operating-system-ebea44feb483))
- Created new environmental variables

[image: environmental variables]

- Adjusted my path

[image: adjusted path]

- Run `ant` within the MALLET folder (received `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`)
- Run `ant jar` within the MALLET folder (received `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`)
- Typed `bin\mallet`, which displays the MALLET commands

However, when I tried to create a `.mallet` file, using `bin\mallet import-dir`, I get the error message `Error: Could not find or load main class cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors`.

I (and my students) will appreciate any help in figuring out how to get this running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a classpath issue. I'm not sure how Java on Windows handles classpath now. Try setting `%MALLET_HOME%` to `C:\Mallet-2.0.8`, not the `bin` directory? The classes would be in `%MALLET_HOME%\class` also, perhaps try adding that to `%PATH%` or `%CLASSPATH%`?

Comment: Changing the `%MALLET_HOME%` environment variable to `C:\mallet-2.0.8` did the trick (after restarting the computer).